# Copy folder structure but only end folder and contents

Tags: powershell, directory, copy

I am trying to work out how to use copy-item (This could change) to copy a folder structure but only keep the end destination. for example

C:\temp\Stack

the above has folders

```
C:\temp\Stack\1\need this and files
C:\temp\Stack\2
C:\temp\Stack\3
```

I want to move to another clients c:\ but keep the structure but only pull in Need this

NEW PC

c:\temp\NEW Folder\Stack\1\need this and files

So would ignore everything else under stack but put in the required directory tree but only include the folder and files from stack\1\need this and files

I need to do this on mass

I am only every getting all or just the end directory copied in

Any help would be amazing

```
get-Content C:\Temp\Source_Transfer\Source.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Verbose -recurse -Path $_ -Destination "\\c:\temp\NEW Folder\Stack\1\need this and files"}
```

This doest copy the file structure before what I need

Comment: You forgot to post your code lol

Comment: @AbrahamZinala added the code that copyies what i need but not the file structure behind it

In the source text i have simply listed 2 or 3 source paths

Comment: What is the meaning of the double backslash in the destination path? If this is supposed to be a UNC path, it should be in the form of `\\serverNameOrIP\Share\Stack\1\need this and files`. Also, without us knowing what is in the input file `Source.txt` this would be hard to answer

Comment: source txt would be C:\temp\Stack\1\need this and files, for this example but i am using unc path as i am copying from one server to another

I an tweaked the script for the example above

Comment: I will try to re-write better when i am finished work, a appreciate the comments though

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be a little more clear. If you're trying to have every folder under C:\temp\Stack\ be copied over you can use this.

```
$Folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\Stack\ -Directory).fullname

$RemoteComputer = "nameorIP"
foreach ($folder in $Folders) {
    $NewFolder = "\\$RemoteComputer\"+'c$'+$folder.substring(2)
    New-Item -Path $NewFolder -ItemType Directory
    Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $NewFolder
}
```